An almost primary decomposition in $K[\![s,t]\!]$
At the beginning of Section 4.1 of this paper, the following (apparently obvious) fact is implicitly assumed:

Let $K$ be a field and $J$ be an ideal in $K[\![s,t]\!]$. There exists $h \in K[\![s,t]\!]$ and an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $K[\![s,t]\!]$ such that, $\mathfrak{a} = K[\![s,t]\!]$ or $\mathfrak{a}$ is a $\langle s,t \rangle$-primary ideal, and $J = \langle h \rangle \cdot \mathfrak{a}$.

I am not entirely sure why this is true. My feeling is that the primary decomposition of $J$ has to be considered:
$$J = \mathfrak{a}_0 \cap \mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \dots \cap \mathfrak{a}_n,$$
where $\mathfrak{a}_0$ is either $K[\![s,t]\!]$ or a $\langle s,t \rangle$-primary ideal. For every $i=1,\dots,n$, the radical $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}_i}$ is a prime ideal of height one, and hence, principal. Still, I don't think this implies that $\mathfrak{a}_i$ is principal, and even it was, we would still have to change "$\cap$" by "$\cdot$" in the primary decomposition.
Thank you for reading. Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Note that $(b)\cap \mathfrak a=b(\mathfrak a:b)$ for any $b\in R$ and $\mathfrak a\trianglelefteq R$. Now if $\mathfrak a$ is $\mathfrak p$-primary and $b\notin \mathfrak a$, then it is an easy exercise to show that $(\mathfrak a:b)$ is $\mathfrak p$-primary.

I forgot to mention that all height one primary ideals in a UFD are principal. (Proof: Let $I$ be a $(p)$-primary ideal. Choose $n$ so that $I\subseteq (p^n)$ but $I\not\subseteq (p^{n+1})$. Let $x\in I\setminus (p^{n+1})$. Since $x\in (p^n)$, we can write $x=yp^n$. Note that because of our choice of $x$, $y\notin (p)=\sqrt I$. Since $I$ is a primary ideal, this implies $p^n\in I$. Hence $I=(p^n)$.)
Furthermore, an intersection of principal ideals is again principal.
The ideal $(r)$ I wrote above comes from intersecting all the height one primary ideals appearing in the decomposition. The first part of my answer explains how to convert the final intersection (with $\mathfrak a_0$ in your notation) into a product.
